# How to Make a centralized data store for reusing of test cases in selenium?

Tags: selenium

how to make centralised data to be reused in various selenium test cases?

Comment: use apache POI for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory in your framework for **testdata** and use **csv/xml/excel** file format as per your convenient and then write a **utility program** to read that data from that directory and pass it  to your script.

Comment: is this a good way of writing ? forums tell to create data set in each and every feature file and use it accordingly.